# Is there a difference between sleeping late and waking up late vs sleeping early and waking up early?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, circadian-rhythms

For example, if I sleep at 1 AM and wake up at 10 AM, will it negatively affect my health opposed to sleeping at 10 PM and waking up at 7 AM?

Comment: To add onto Louis' answer briefly, there are a lot of factors at play in this question. The way your own circadian rhythm has been set will play a role - any change away from your normal routine will be met with stress. Also, other factors like eating times and light cues that normally affect waking time will play a role in determining whether either of those schedules will impact your health. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can provide a more complete answer.

Comment: In short: yes, absolutely there's a difference. Currently I'm at work, but when I get home I'll hopefully be free to provide a sufficient response to this. What @Shafter eludes to though, is accurate, and is similar to the basis that I'll be utilizing in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a popular theory that each person has a certain "chronotype" [Ref 1]. Based on your genetics, you could be naturally an early person ("Lark") or a late person ("Owl") [Ref. 2].  What will negatively affect your health is actually fighting what you naturally are.  You probably know which chronotype you are, and if not you can go by what time you naturally sleep/wake when you don't have school/job scheduling such as at the weekend.

[Ref. 1]:[Chronotype Review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12568247)
[Ref. 2]:[Social jetlag paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16687322)

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! Could you please add references to your claims? Answers without references maybe challenged or deleted. For more information please have a look at our [how to answer guide](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note there is also evidence chronotype can change with age. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5479630/